# AngularJS Object empty array, member is filled in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having this wierd issue that when I call on my object it's emtpy, but when I call on a specific value of that object I can see the values.

HTML

```
<input id="Title" type="text" class="upload-input required" ng-change="change()"
        ng-model-options="{ debounce: 350 }" ng-model="video.Title">
<label for="Title" ng-class="{active: video.Title}" translate="video.title">
```

this was working before, but don't know why this behaviour is happening

[image: Error]

Comment: Hehe it seems to be miracle :D. Please replicate it on fiddle or plunker then we can help you :P

Comment: Your `scope.video` is an empty array, not an `object` in the way you intend it to be. Try setting `scope.video = {}`

Comment: @JibiAbraham that's correct, thanks! can you post this as an aswer so I can mark it as the sollution?